# Is `is` correct in this sentence? Or it should be `was`?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Here's a context. A person has changed his main Facebook email address to `example@gmail.com`. His previous email address `is/was` `foobar@gmail.com`. Assuming that the person will never change his Facebook email address anymore, I have this sentence:

`The email address that was associated with his Facebook account is foobar@gmail.com`.

I was thinking that `is foobar@gmail.com` can be correct since the previous email address will never change (i.e., in the future, the previous email address would still be `foobar@gmail.com`). On the other hand, using `was foobar@gmail.com` sounds natural but I don't understand why it would be correct because I thought that `was` is used to refer to a past event and `foobar@gmail.com` is not an event.

I appreciate if someone could help me with my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be best to use **was** since it is in the past.

> The email address that was associated with his Facebook account **was** foobar@gmail.com.

Your confusion might be from

> The email address **is** foobar@gmail.com, that **was** associated with his Facebook account is foobar@gmail.com.
>
> Q: What **was** associated with his Facebook account?
>   A: That email address **is** foobar@gmail.com.

But using "**was**", eventhough repetitive, would be best.

> The email address **was** foobar@gmail.com, that **was** associated with his Facebook account is foobar@gmail.com.
>
> Q: What **was** associated with his Facebook account?
>   A: That email address **was** foobar@gmail.com.

Comment: Peter, do you mean that using `is` is wrong?

Comment: Not at all, but there may be an ambiguity using "**is**". In my second example (which is the same as your example), what is being talked about is the email address *at that time*, this is established with additional context. You would be able to use "**was**" without all the additional context but most people would still understand what you are saying if you use "**is**".